# System Design for Aws IAM Policy or GCP policy evaluation

Tags: architecture, system, amazon-iam, google-cloud-iam

How can we design a policy evaluation system like aws IAM or google IAM, any guidance will help.
**Key Functionality:**

1. what kind of structure should we use for permission evaluation? for ex. one user can have multiple policy attached to same resource(s3 bucket policy as well as aws IAM custom policy). how to determine if user action is allowed or denied? Do we need to represent in specific types of tree? How will this policy evaluation scale[may depend on previous answer] ?
   ***Sample Policy JSON***

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{ -->Can have multiple statement 
    "Effect": "Allow", -> allow or deny
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::********",
                 "arn:aws:s3:::**********/*"],
    "Condition": -> any condition
    }
  ]
}
```

Initially I have thought of designing system for policy evaluation only.Now I am looking into [KeyCloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak) as it is an open source IAM tool, and [AWS IAM Functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html)& [Permission Boundaries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html#access_policies_boundaries-eval-logic).Aws json policy schema/example can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#access_policies-json). Please help.

Comment: This may give you some ideas https://youtu.be/lsH2dYh-_3g

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for opinions/recommendations which makes your question off-topic. There is no one single correct answer. Ask questions that present a problem that can be solved with a fact-based answer.

The security designs of AWS and Google Cloud are very different. I would not try to shoehorn AWS' style of authorization with Google Cloud's or the reverse. Each vendor approaches security in equally strong ways using very different implementations.